# image is not fitting the Container | Boxfit.fill?

Tags: flutter

I would like the image to fill the entire `Container` however I am unable to do so. Documents and resources online are pointing to using `fit: BoxFit.fill` however, it does not appear to be valid.

Am I missing something that would cause the photo to not fill the entire container, and thus not follow the `childAspectRatio`

```
 : GridView.count(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            crossAxisCount: 2,
            childAspectRatio: (50 / 80),
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
               children:
                     List.generate(widget.imageArray.length, (index) {
                return Container(
                     child: Image.file(widget.imageArray[index]),
                     decoration: BoxDecoration(
                     color: Colors.grey[800],
                     borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                      fit: BoxFit.fill,
        ));
   }))
```

Comment: use ```BoxFit.cover```

Comment: @EhsanAskari that does not seem to work either

Comment: set container height and width and use BoxFit.cover

Comment: @AkshayNayka  As I mentioned above... that method does not work. Unless I am mistaken for how I am doing so. Could you provide an answer?

Comment: your code will not compile at all, since `Container` does not have `fill` property, you need `child: Image.file(widget.imageArray[index], fit: BoxFit.fill),` instead

Answer (score 0):

```
: GridView.count(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            crossAxisCount: 2,
            childAspectRatio: (50 / 80),
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
               children:
                     List.generate(widget.imageArray.length, (index) {
                return Container(
                     child: Image.file(widget.imageArray[index],fit: BoxFit.fill,),
                    // use BoxFit.fill or BoxFit.cover as you need
                     decoration: BoxDecoration(
                     color: Colors.grey[800],
                     borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    // not need this here
                    //  fit: BoxFit.fill,
        ));
   }))
```